# Open id connect access token expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, access-token, openid-connect

We are using Open id connect authentication code flow to get refresh token and access token from external authorization server. I am thinking on using IdentityModel library to retrieve the tokens from the code.

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel2/blob/dev/README.md

Tokens would be stored in database with the expiration date.

I would like to know the best practice to check if the access token is expired. I understand that one of the following ways would be helpful to achieve so. Would like to know if there is cleaner and better approach.

1. Access the protected service using the expired token. Guess it would throw an exception
2. Compare the expiration date with the today date.
3. Is there a way in IdentityModel library to check for the expiration of access token?

Any other better approach?

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this. First get the access token with the code

```
        _tokenClient = new TokenClient(_options.Authority);
        var response = await _tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync("CODE", "http://myuri");
        var token = response.AccessToken;
        var validUntil = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(response.ExpiresIn);
```

Later I can use this value to check if the token is still valid. You can store the valid until value in the database or attach it to your users session.

```
        if(DateTime.Now >= validUntil)
        {
            // token expired
        }
```

I usually subtract a couple of minutes from this value - so I don't have to wait until the last minute before refreshing the token.

Comment: Thanks. Do you encrypt / hash the token while storing in database?

Comment: I'm not storing it in the db, I keep it in memory, if I loose it I get a new one. However I'm using this with the client credentials flow, not the auth code one. If you hash the token, you wont be able to use it anymore, so this kind of misses the point. Of course you could use the hash as an index if you only want to store the valid time. IMO storing access tokens in a DB makes little sense, as the only live for a short time (<60min)

Comment: We get this token from external authentication server, and the expiration that they provide is more than a day and it could vary when 'refresh'. Hence  we have decided to store in db.

Comment: I'm not an expert on security, but I'd lean towards encrypting it, provided you can store the key in a secure location, (I think windows has means for this but I've never done it).